# Send sms from client android Twilio?

Tags: android, rest, twilio, twilio-api

Hi would like to send an sms verification to users phone numbers.I have done it in ios by calling the rest Api and it works.
But can anyone help me with android I get an error : 
**code=401, message=UNAUTHORIZED**.
Any help would be apreciated?

```
url = https://{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/AccountsAccountSid}/SMS/Messages

private OkHttpClient mClient2 = new OkHttpClient();
Call post(String url, Callback callback) throws IOException {
    Random rand = new Random();
     randomNum = 1000 + rand.nextInt((100000 - 1000) + 1);
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
       .add("To", etNumber.getText().toString())

        .add("From", "+mynum")

        .add("Body", "Your confirmation code for United taxi is" + randomNum)
       .build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();


    Call response = mClient2.newCall(request);

    System.out.println(request.url());
    response.enqueue(callback);
    return response;

}
```

The WWW-Authenticate header is:

WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Twilio API"

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

I actually happen to have written a blog post explaining why you shouldn't make requests like this directly from the device, but have a server in the middle. It will not only make your account more secure, but make it much easier to debug.

Best of all, even if you don't wanna build a backend yourself, my blog post shows you how to deploy one with the click of a button.

Check it out [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html) or get started with your [server-side language of choice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) and finish up with the post.

As for the error you're getting, **UNAUTHORIZED** implies you're not passing the correct AccountSid & AuthToken. If you still want to go down the route of making the request directly from the device, which again, we don't recommend, I would suggest trying to make the request from something like Postman for example, to make sure you've got your credentials right, and then moving that to the device using OkHttp.

Comment: My credential are copied right from the console.So i do not think they are wrong?

Comment: I have used the same for ios but there is no error.